# add tracking to an existing function in postgres plpgsql

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a postgres table that gets its data (Inserts/Updates/Deletes) from a function that performs these operations.

I am looking to add tracking functionality to that function so that it automatically adds the old value, new value, the type of operation performed on the table (insert/update/delete), and the timestamp on a new table.

I am trying to make the logging table in the following format:

```
old_val    new_val   Type_of_operation      Timestamp         
 ---------|---------|-------------------|--------------------| 
  a,b,c,d | w,x,y,z | update            | 11:09PM 01/08/2019 |  
  1,2,3,4 |         | delete            | 2:05PM 02/12/2018  |  
          | ki,hjko | insert            | 09:00AM 02/10/2018 |
```

I was explicitly asked not to use triggers and to use plpgsql.

Is there anyway that i can modify the function to simultaneously add to the logging table along with the original table along with the type of operation in plpgsql.?

Comment: Have already looked at using logical decoding available in postgres.That plugin is currently disabled at my company and will not be made available any time soon.

Comment: *I am looking to add tracking functionality to that function...Is there anyway that i can modify the function"* - where's that function? why not show us what's already there and save us some effort to write what's already there? Posting the structure of the table would also be greatly helpful.